# Failed to resolve support-v4 27.1.0 dependency in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library

I am trying to build an app on Android 27 and facing issues when I add android com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0 and com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1 dependencies.

My Project Gradle file looks like this -

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My App build.gradle file looks like this -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.webinar"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am getting the following error while building on Android Studio 3.1.0 -
[image: Build Errors]

Can someone please help me how to get support-v4:27.1.0 to work for my app?

Comment: do you have the support repository installed and updated?

Comment: @TimCastelijns My SDK Manager shows Android Support Repository updated to version 47.0.0. Is there something else which I am missing?

Comment: and google repository

Comment: @TimCastelijns Google Repository is updated to version 58

Comment: Select one of "google()"  or "maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }" in your root build.gradle file's repositories sections they does the same thing.

Comment: @tema_man I removed `google()` from the project `build.gradle` and still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

it seems your gradle is offline or you have enable proxy

Comment: I am connected to the internet and I am not connected to any proxy. I think I would check that first before posting a question SO